# Beginner-jJava- Amazon Elastic Beanstalk- Unable to correctly specify health check url-also,what is base url

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have created a sample web application in Java. It has no errors, and I was able to create a WAR archive successfully. I also tested this successfully in local Tomcat 7 server.

Now, this sample web app has 2 servlets- "home" and "runsinglecrawljob". The name of the war archive is "sparkcrawler0.12.war".

So, in local Tomcat, I access the web app at

```
 http://localhost:8080/SparkCrawler0.12/runsinglecrawljob
```

And the other servlet is

```
 http://localhost:8080/SparkCrawler0.12/home
```

Now, when I created an Elastic Beanstalk environment, I specified health check url="/home"

But I am getting error that health check url is not responsive, and because of this the application is not running in Elastic Beanstalk- it is showing a 503 error- as per Google Chrome this is the exact message --

"HTTP Error 503 (Service Unavailable): The server is currently unable to handle the request. This code indicates this is a temporary condition, and the server will be up again after a delay."

Now, what is the correct value of health check URL?

Also, if my URL is

```
 http://spark.elasticbeanstalk.com
```

as defined in Elastic Beanstalk, then do I access the web app at

```
 http://spark.elasticbeanstalk.com/SparkCrawler0.12/runsinglecrawljob
```

Or do I access the web app at

```
 http://spark.elasticbeanstalk.com/runsinglecrawljob ?
```

Comment: Did you try `/SparkCrawler0.12/home` as your health check URL? Also if you're getting negative health checks, your ELB won't register active instances, which is why you can't reach the webapp.

Comment: @Christopher I tried the url as suggested by you, but still facing same problem... any more ideas? thanks...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is related or not, but I have a very similar issue but with a PHP codeigniter application.

I uploaded the application, and 'index.php' is the normal starting point of the application.
I also have a simple "phpinfo.php" that sits parallel to the index.php.

So, the URL is myApp.elasticbeanstalk.com which hits index.php and it is fine.

However, for my health check, I set it to /phpinfo.php  because I want myApp.elasticbeanstalk.com/phpinfo.php to be used as the health check.

If I do this, the health check always fails, and so my application does not run and I see the glaring red box of doom.

This has been driving me crazy.

(Why do I want to do this?  -- it's because I wanted to add an .htaccess file to the application root that requires a password for everything except the phpinfo.php file, and I tested this locally and it works.   I did not add the .htaccess file yet -- I just wanted to see if I could point the health check to something besides "/" and have it work.

UPDATE --
I sorted out my issue.  It turns out that when I launch one of these elastic beanstalk environments, I have to set up the healthcheck url right then and there to be /phpinfo.php  and then upload my application.    When I was fussing with this earlier, I would try to edit the configuration later to change the health check url and that never worked and the instance would never come alive again.